# Display function name in status-line

Tags: emacs

I'd like to have the function name displayed next to the buffer name
on the mode-line if the point is inside a function (maybe with some reasonable truncation if necessary).

Is ther a simple way to achieve this? (via imenu? defuns?)

Example: in `test.py` if my cursor is inside `def myfunction`, I'd like  my mode-line say:

```
test.py: myfunction
```

Could be also interesting for org mode (displaying the inside-most header)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Which Function Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhichFuncMode) should help you :

> WhichFuncMode (also known as WhichFunctionMode) is a minor mode, that when activated displays the current function name in the mode line. It works under certain major modes, like CcMode or PerlMode.

To activate this minor mode : <kbd>M-x</kbd> `which-function-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>

An interesting effect of this mode is by middle-clicking on the current function name : it can narrow the display to the current function.

Comment: yeah... I've found it after posting the question... was googling for it before with no success...

Comment: @user673592: I have the same "problem": often discovering the answer right after asking on SO :)

Answer (score 4):

OK... I found it: the mode is built in and can be globally activated by:

```
(which-function-mode 1)
```

Change colors and add major modes (e.g. org-mode is not enabled by default) with:

`M-x customize-group` and selecting `which-func`